# How would they really test the Google Signup Page?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Can someone tell me what are possible scenarios there can be to test the [Google Signup](https://accounts.google.com/signup) Page using Selenium Java?. I'm a very beginner for selenium. I just know how to test the fields and all. But, like the logo, the images, their size, resolution I don't know how to. Can anyone explain me how to?... I'm really expecting a technical experts perspective.

Comment: This is not a programming question. What have you tried and what was the result? Post your code and the issues you are running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get size of any element you can use below sample snippet

```
 WebElement wElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xPath_goes_her"));
 int wElementWidth = wElement.getSize().getWidth();
 int wElementHeight = wElement.getSize().getHeight();
```